# Mozart K331 Rondo Alla Turca m.55 discrepancy (Urtext vs Urtext?)

Tags: piano, sheet-music, mozart, sonata, editions

I have the Wiener **Urtext** edition of the Mozart K331 (see cover image). As you can see in the picture, the 4th note of measure 55 of the Rondo Alla Turca is **A** (E#FG**A**). However, I saw two videos where people play the **F** note: E#FG**F**. I found an [online sheet music](https://www.sheet-music.online/turkish-march-sheet-music-download-rondo-alla-turca-by-mozart.html) that claims to be based on **urtext** editions and it also has **F** instead of **A** (somehow it's measure 59 there, not m.55)(see image).

In the preface of the Wiener edition, re available sources, it says "For two other sonatas (K.331 and K. 570), at least some fragments of the original manuscript have been preserved."

So which version is (more likely?) the original Or most adopted?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Any score from an online publisher should be viewed with *great* skepticism. I would trust the one from an established, reputable publisher.

Comment: I bought the Wiener edition because I trust it's authoritive, however so far I have seen 4 videos all playing the F, not A (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-pg-lMoCFY   and   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLKj1cflsAo    also that 6 year old kid :) ). Haven't found one playing the Wiener version yet.

Comment: Turns out someone had asked about the very same measure some years ago (stumbled upon by accident): https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11071/rondo-alla-turca-bar-55  (please don't delete this question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below comes from the [Henle commentary](https://www.henle.de/en/detail/?Title=Piano%20Sonata%20A%20major%20K.%20331%20(300i)%20(with%20Alla%20Turca)_1300) on their 2021 edition.

> 55 u: In F<sub>1</sub> 4th note indistinct, rather b<sup>2</sup> than a<sup>2</sup>; F<sub>4</sub> has b<sup>2</sup>; C, C<sub>PR</sub> have a<sup>2</sup>, rendered thus in our edition, cf. also M 39. Many later editions correct the reading of F<sub>4</sub> to f#<sup>2</sup>.

The sources referenced are given substantive explanations in the commentary, but briefly:

- C: Undated copyist's manuscript. It " became known in 2016. It contains numerous textual mistakes." Possibly dating to 1760s or 1770s.
- C<sub>PR</sub>: Copyist's manuscript. Likely late 18th century.
- F<sub>*n*</sub>: First edition, *n*th printing.

Henle is also saying that the A is preferred over F# by comparison with m. 39, which contains the same musical material, but leading to a cadence on C# minor rather than F# minor.

[image: K.311 m. 39]

Since the corresponding sections of the piece are largely parallel to each other, Henle considers the earlier passage to be the defining factor. This, given that the copyists agree, the first editions are ambiguous (or presumptively wrong), and the F# is an editorial correction not backed up by other sources.

However, the F# (instead of A) is harmonically justifiable as a necessary modification to avoid the awkward diminished fourth from A to E#.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is more detailed than I could have expected. (Does b^2 refer to the F# note, a^2 refer to the A note?)

Comment: @GrandAdagio No, b2 literally means the note b, one step above the a used in their edition.

Comment: Oh, I see, so some even printed B instead of A. Thanks again for taking the time to find the answer.